# How do i paste consecutive values in a dataframe together into a new column

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse

I want to paste consecutive values in a dataframe into a new column in the same dataframe.

my dataframe is this:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| blue | A234 |
| green,black | A5 |
| yellow | A6 |
| blue,green,purple | A7 |

I want to have a third column 'z', that will paste the values in 'x', like this:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| blue | A234 | blue |
| green,black | A5 | blue,green,black |
| yellow | A6 | blue,green,black,yellow |
| blue,green,purple | A7 | blue,green,purple,blue,green,black,yellow |

Answer (score 1):

In `tidyverse`, this can be done with `accumulate` and `paste/str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(z = accumulate(x, str_c, sep=","))
```

-output

```
#                x    y                                         z
#1              blue A234                                      blue
#2       green,black   A5                          blue,green,black
#3            yellow   A6                   blue,green,black,yellow
#4 blue,green,purple   A7 blue,green,black,yellow,blue,green,purple
```

---

Or a similar option with `Reduce` from `base R`

```
Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep=","), df1$x, accumulate = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c("blue", "green,black", "yellow", "blue,green,purple"
), y = c("A234", "A5", "A6", "A7")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```